# Encode smart contract function call with parameters

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, erc-721, python

I'm trying to encode a function call on a ERC721 smart contract.

I'm using web3-python package to use some utils.

Here is my code:

```
from web3 import Web3

r = Web3.soliditySha3(['bytes32'], [b'tokenURI(uint256)'])
0xc87b56dda752230262935940d907f047a9f86bb5ee6aa33511fc86db33fea6cc

r[0:10]
0xc87b56dd
```

This code works partially: I get the signature of the function (0xc87b56dd). However, I want to pass an argument and encode it with the function name together.

So if I want to pass `275` as a parameter, I should get this result instead (at the end of the hash, `113` is `275` hex value):

```
0xc87b56dd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000113
```

I don't know how to achieve that. I read a lot of forums but can't find the right way to do it.

Basically I want to achieve what [this](https://abi.hashex.org) website is doing.

Comment: Something like [contract.encodeABI](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.encodeABI)?

Comment: How do you implement that?

Comment: Do you really want to implement ABI encoding? In that case read the ABI specification here https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html. If you want to use it then just create a `contract` object.

Answer (score 1):

In solidity, I have the following :

```
contract TestContract {
    uint256 public i;
    function callMe(uint256 j, uint256 a) public payable {
        console.log("TestContract.callMe(%d,%d) called", j, a);
        i += j;
    }
    function getData(uint256 j, uint256 a) public view returns (bytes memory) {
        console.log("call signature encoded:");
        console.logBytes(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("callMe(uint256,uint256)", j, a)
        );
        return abi.encodeWithSignature("callMe(uint256,uint256)", j, a);
    }
}
```

In Python (brownie), I will call the function as following:

```
    v = 123
    a = 10000
    encoded_signature = t.getData(v, a)
    print(encoded_signature)
    sig = Web3.keccak(text="callMe(uint256,uint256)")[:4].hex()
    v_hex = convert.to_bytes(v).hex()
    a_hex = convert.to_bytes(a).hex()
    data = sig+v_hex+a_hex
    print(data)
    assert encoded_signature == data
```

Well, the idea is to obtain the function signature and to concatenate with parameter values converted to bytes.